# Getting a Segmentation fault because of conditions in while loop

Tags: c++

Im making a hash table out of a string array, and in my insert, I have a while statement thats there to handle collisions and wrap arounds.  I have played around with it, and seem to only get a segmentation fault 11 when the conditional statements are used.  Heres the while loop I have:

```
while (numElm != length)
{
    numProbes = 0;
    int index = hash( newGuest );
    //handles collision and wraparound
    while (hashArray[index] != " " && hashArray[index] != "-1")
    {
        ++index;
        index %= length;
        numProbes = numProbes + 1;
    }

    //sets the array at the index eqaul to data
    hashArray[index] = newGuest;
    cout << newGuest << " has been inserted at index: " << index << " using " << numProbes << " probes";
    break;

}
```

The problem occurs when the second while loop begins with the two conditional statements. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

**edit** the rest of the program

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include "HashTable.h"

using namespace std;

//typedef double value_type;


HashTable::HashTable( int tableLength )
{   
    tableLength = 114;
    string *hashArray = new string[tableLength];
    length = tableLength;
    numElm = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        hashArray[i] = " ";
    }
}


// Returns an array location for a given item key.
int HashTable::hash( string itemKey )
{
    int value = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < itemKey.size(); i++ )
    {
        value += itemKey[i];
    }
    return (value * itemKey.length() ) % length;
}

// Adds an item to the Hash Table.
void HashTable::insertGuest( string newGuest )
{
//  int index = hash( newGuest );   
    //hashArray[ index ].insertGuest( newGuest );
//  cout << newGuest << " has been inserted at index: " << index;

//  string s = " ";
    while (numElm != length)
    {
        numProbes = 0;
        int index = hash( newGuest );
        //handles collision and wraparound
        while (hashArray[index] != " " && hashArray[index] != "-1")
        {
            ++index;
            index %= length;
            numProbes = numProbes + 1;
        }

        //sets the array at the index eqaul to data
        hashArray[index] = newGuest;
        cout << newGuest << " has been inserted at index: " << index << " using " << numProbes << " probes";
        break;

    }
}

// De-allocates all memory used for the Hash Table.
HashTable::~HashTable()
{
    delete [] hashArray;
}
//#endif
```

Comment: What is the declaration of `hashArray`? In fact. please give a full [mcve].

Comment: Your `index` obviously goes beyond `hashArray`. Tried debugging?

Comment: Are you sure `hash(newGuest)` always returns a valid index that is not outside the array boundaries?

Comment: For future reference: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: @arrowd I've tried debugging, but it does not even let me get pass the first run through of the loop.  It sort of just keeps running as if its stuck testing the conditional statements

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...), improve your code to get no warnings, then **use the debugger** (`gdb`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't initialize your *member* variable `hashArray`, only a *local* variable `hashArray` in your constructor. The `hashArray` in your class remains uninitialized and causes a crash when used. To fix, replace

```
string *hashArray = new string[tableLength];
```

with

```
hashArray = new string[tableLength];
```

This fixes the problem. There are many stylistic and code-wise problems with the code otherwise, but I hope you will continue to learn to fix those on your own. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! Cant believe it was that simple!

Comment: Try turning up warnings. I know that MSVC (which you may be using) has a warning for this exact problem.